# Method signature C++

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, operators, signature

Having trouble understanding method signature in C++. Looking for a second opinion.

`readPage(File* file, const PageId pageNo, Page*& page) {}`

The above can be re-written as follows?

`readPage(File *file, const PageId pageNo, Page *&page) {}`

So, *file is pointer that is being passed in and *&page is something's address that is then converted to a pointer? I'm confused with the combination of `*&`

Comment: Read about references in your favorite C++ textbook. `page` has the type "a reference to a pointer to `Page`".

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference

Comment: Whitespace does not matter here - both signatures are equivalent.

Comment: A good and easy explanation is given [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/pointers/article.php/c4089/PointertoPointer-and-ReferencetoPointer.htm)

Answer (score 0):

`file` is a pointer to a `File`, which means that any changes to what it points to, like

```
file->doSomething(); // the caller will see this change
```

will be seen by the calling side, but if one overwrites the pointer, that not only the new value of the pointer not going to be seen by the caller, but any changes to the file after that will also not be observed, because it's a pointer to a different `File` now, and because the pointer itself is passed by value.

```cpp
file = new File(); // the caller will not see this change
file->doSomething(); // neither will it see this one
```

Now, `page` is a reference to a pointer to a `Page`. In other words, it behaves like a pointer, so

```cpp
page->doSomething(); // the caller will see this change
```

is still observed by the caller. But now if you overwrite the pointer, the caller's pointer will also be changed, and hence all consecutive changes will also be seen:

```cpp
page = new Page(); // caller also sees this change
page->doSomething(); // and this too
```

This is because the pointer itself is passed by reference, so any changes to the pointer itself are observed by the calling side.

(and yes, the way you place spaces does not matter, so the two ways you provided are identical)

Comment: I'm testing this out and understand that I need to pass in a pointer to readPage to match File *file but for Page *&page I also need to pass in a pointer it looks like. But unclear on how it is interpreted once passed in.

Is *&id and *id almost analogous? In both cases it evaluates to a pointer.

Comment: The difference is similar to that between `int` and `int&`. In both cases you can pass in an `int` variable, but in the second case all the changes to it will be observed by the caller. Similarly, here in both cases (`file*` and `page*&`) you pass a pointer, but in the latter case changes to the pointer are seen by the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Page*& is reference to pointer to a Page